# How to make such kind of custom shape drawable?

Tags: android, android-drawable

[image: Create custom shape like this]

How to make such kind of drawable(show in white) in android which has such kind of curves?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use [9patch](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch) images for such purposes. You could find some online editors like [Simple nine-patch generator](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html#&sourceDensity=320&name=example) . Just put your image inside and draw Stretch region & Content padding with lines.

Another option is to use SVG format which could be better because of smaller file size and [vector graphics](https://www.fileformat.info/mirror/egff/ch04_09.htm). On the other hand it is harder to implement it because not all elements are supported. You can read about it in [official docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio)
It is possible to find some online tools to convert your image to SVG like [SVG Creator](https://svgcreator.com/)
To avoid `Android + SVG` restrictions you could use third party libs like [SvgGlidePlugin](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6812) or a lot of others.

However I suggest to try 9patch firstly.